# R automatically adding two way interactions when working on three ways

Tags: r, statistics

First time using this, not sure if it's better suited to Stack Overflow or Cross Validated.

I'm running a Logistic regression in R. I found a significant three way interaction between some of my variables (All three are quantitative). However when  I add the three way interaction to the model it automatically includes all possible two way interactions of those three which I don't want.

```
gg<-glm(EVER_SMOKED~AGE+BIS_Cog_Instability+BIS_self_control+DOS_Fin_Investment+DOS_Fin_Gambling+DOS_HealthSafety+BIS_Cog_Instability*BIS_self_control*DOS_Fin_Gambling ,data=data,family="binomial")
```

Output: 
[Link to output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhRFX.png)

In summary, I only want the model to include the single and three way interaction, not all the two way interactions.

Comment: You can do this but statisticians advise against it.

Comment: A careful reading of `?formula` would help here. `*` includes all lower order interactions. If you read the documentation there on formulas, you'll see lots of other ways of specifying terms exactly using `:`. (But I also agree with Roland.)

Comment: What @Roland and joran said and also: multiplying *quantitative* values together to obtain an interaction is mathematically okay but the interaction is less flexible than interactions between categorical variables and may be hard to interpret.

Comment: Cheers, including the " : " worked as I wanted. You where all correct however, it introduced other issues I hadn't expected. 

Thank you for the help!

Comment: For future reference, it is frequently recommended to include output text itself and not an image of it.